# How to remove [] in qweb when print sql output

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-12, qweb

1. I run this code for odoo 12
2. i need the output just 2
3. but when i print, the print out show [2]
4. can someone help me to remove [] in qweb
5. get_report is method to print report

This my python code:

```
@api.multi
#Call when button 'Get Report' clicked
    def get_report(self):
        sql = """SELECT 1+1"""
        self.env.cr.execute(sql)
        res_one = self.env.cr.fetchone()
        data = {
            'ids': self.ids,
            'model': self._name,
            'form': {
                'sql': res_one
            },
        }
        ###use self.env.ref('module_name.report_id') as reference. report_action() will call 
        ###_get_report_values() and pass 'data{}' automatically.
        return self.env.ref('trabaud.recap_report').report_action(self, data=data)

@api.multi
    def _get_report_values(self, docids, data=None):
        sql = data['form']['sql']

        return {
            'sql': sql
        }
```

This My XML

```
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr style="text-align:center">
        <td style="width:30%;"/>
        <td style="width:15%; text-align:left; padding: 0px;">Kode Barang</td>
        <td style="width:2%; text-align:left; padding: 0px;">:</td>
        <td style="width:23%; text-align:left; padding: 0px;"><b><span t-esc="kode"/></b></td>
        <td style="width:30%;"/>
    </tr>
    <tr style="text-align:center">
        <td style="width:30%;"/>
        <td style="width:15%; text-align:left; padding: 0px;">Lokasi</td>
        <td style="width:2%; text-align:left; padding: 0px;">:</td>
        <td style="width:23%; text-align:left; padding: 0px;"><b><span t-esc="gudang_name"/></b></td>
        <td style="width:30%;"/>
    </tr>
    <tr style="text-align:center">
        <td style="width:30%;"/>
        <td style="width:15%; text-align:left; padding: 0px;">Tahun</td>
        <td style="width:2%; text-align:left; padding: 0px;">:</td>
        <td style="width:23%; text-align:left; padding: 0px;"><b><span t-esc="sql"/></b></td>
        <td style="width:30%;"/>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and this print out result (https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlSUe.png)

Comment: Try `sql = data['form']['sql'][0]`.

Comment: thanks @Selcuk `sql = data['form']['sql'][0]` its works